# How To write DTD for this XML?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, dtd

How to write DTD for this XML code ?

```
<Customers>
    <Customer CustomerID="ALFKI" CompanyName="Alfreds Futterkiste" />
</Customers>
```

Comment: What part of this is giving you difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

### Rosetta Stone of XML schemas for a simple XML document

```
<Customers>
    <Customer CustomerID="ALFKI" CompanyName="Alfreds Futterkiste" />
</Customers>
```

**DTD:**

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT Customers (Customer+)>
<!ELEMENT Customer EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST Customer
  CompanyName CDATA #REQUIRED
  CustomerID NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Customers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Customer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="CompanyName" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="CustomerID" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**RELAX NG:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar ns="" xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0" datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">
  <start>
    <element name="Customers">
      <oneOrMore>
        <element name="Customer">
          <attribute name="CompanyName"/>
          <attribute name="CustomerID">
            <data type="NCName"/>
          </attribute>
        </element>
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>
</grammar>
```

**RELAX NC:**

```
default namespace = ""

start =
  element Customers {
    element Customer {
      attribute CompanyName { text },
      attribute CustomerID { xsd:NCName }
    }+
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE Customers
[
    <!ELEMENT Customers (Customer+)>
    <!ELEMENT Customer EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST Customer CustomerID CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ATTLIST Customer CompanyName CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```